# mysql.connector, multi=True, sql variable assignment not working

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-connector

SQL code (all in one file that is eventually saved in the python variable "query"):

```
select @dtmax:=DATE_FORMAT(max(dt), '%Y%m') from table_A;
delete from table_B where  DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y%m')=@dtmax;
```

Does mysql-connector allow the use of variable assignment like I've done in the query above. i.e. take the value of max(date) from TABLE_A and delete everything with that date from TABLE_B.

python code:

```
    c = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
    c.execute(query, multi=True)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

All I know is that the 2nd SQL statement doesnt execute.

I can copy and paste the SQL code into Toad and run it there without any problems but not through mysql.connector library. I would have used pandas but this is legacy script written by someone else and I don't have time to re-write everything.

I kindly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you use `multi=True`, then `execute()` will return a generator. You need to iterate over that generator to actually advance the processing to the next sql statement in your multi-statement query:

```
c = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
results = c.execute(query, multi=True)
for cur in results:
    print('cursor:', cur)
    if cur.with_rows:
        print('result:', cur.fetchall())
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

`cur.with_rows` will be `True` if there are results to fetch for the current statement.

This is all described in the documentation of [`MySQLCursor.execute()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)