# INSERT function doesn't throw errors, still not updating DB table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am creating a Mysql Wrapper for Python, mainly just to learn the ins and outs of the language etc. Though I stumble upon an issue I can't see to find a solution for.

When I run the script, there are no exceptions thrown, though my DB doesn't get updated. I played around with the DB Cursors, like closing them, creating new one in the function etc. But the result remains the same.

aka: cursor.rowcount -1

Connecting to the DB:

```py
class magicDB:
    myDB = None
    DB_Cursor = None

    def __init__(self,host, user, passwd, DB=None):
        global myDB
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.DB = DB

        if self.DB is None:
            myDB = mysql.connector.connect(
                host= host,
                user= user,
                passwd= passwd)
            #DB_Cursor = myDB.cursor()
        else:
            myDB = mysql.connector.connect(
                host= host,
                user= user,
                passwd= passwd,
                database=DB)
            #DB_Cursor = myDB.cursor()
    def insert(self,table_name, params):


            fields = ''
            values = ''
            placeholders = ''

            query = '"INSERT INTO {} '. format(table_name)
            for key in params:
                fields = fields + str(key) + ', '
                values = values + str(params[key]) + ', '
                placeholders = placeholders + str('%s, ')

            fields = fields[:-2]
            values = values[:-2]
            placeholders = placeholders[:-2]
            query = query + '(' + fields + ')' + ' VALUES ' + '(' + placeholders + ')"'
            print(query)
            try:
                Cursor = myDB.cursor()
                Cursor.execute(operation=query, params=values, multi=True)
                myDB.commit()
                print(Cursor.rowcount, ' Record inserted')
            except mysql.connector.Error as error:
                print (error)
            finally:    
                Cursor.close()
```

And this is the main module that calls the functions:

```py
from db_magic import magicDB

conn = magicDB(host='localhost', user='***', passwd='****', DB='testing')
print(conn)


# print(conn.DB_create('testing2'))


conn.insert(table_name= 'users', params={
    'user_name': 'John Doe',
    'email' : 'test@123.com',
    'password': 'test'

} )
print(conn.Close_conn())
```

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong here, as there are no exceptions thrown.

SOLUTION:

Changed the values to a list instead of a string.

```py
def insert(self,table_name, params):      
        fields = ''
        values = [] # changed to List instead of String
        placeholders = ''

        query = 'INSERT INTO {} '. format(table_name)
        for key in params:
            fields = fields + str(key) + ', '
            values.append(params[key])
            placeholders = placeholders + str('%s, ')

        fields = fields[:-2]
        placeholders = placeholders[:-2]
        query = query + '(' + fields + ')' + ' VALUES ' + '(' + placeholders + ')'
        print(query)
        print(values)
        try:
            Cursor = myDB.cursor()
            Cursor.execute(operation=query, params=values, multi=False)
            myDB.commit()
            print(Cursor.rowcount, ' Record inserted')
        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print(error)
        except:
            print ('Some errors')
        finally:    
            Cursor.close()
```

Comment: you need to do `conn.commit()` to actually save all the changes

Comment: Yeah, I am calling myDB.commit() after the execute function in the 'Try / Except' statement.

Comment: Have you tried changing `except mysql.connector.Error as error` to `except Exception as error` to check that there is not an error of a different type?

Comment: That's good thinking indeed. Changed it to just an except: and print('errors thrown') but still same outcome unfortunate, no errors.

Comment: I see there are several print statements in the code - what output do they produce when you run it?

Comment: I'm starting to run out of ideas, what is the output of `print(query)`?

Comment: print(query) results in: "INSERT INTO users (user_name, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" and 
print(Cursor.rowcount, ' Record inserted') gives: -1  Record inserted

Comment: [mysql.connector, multi=True, sql variable assignment not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32257894)

Comment: Ah lads, got it solved. 
The values, I had here was a string. I have changed it to an list, and that works.

Comment: Also @SmartManoj, your solution taught me that I was using multi=True completely wrong. I thought it was used for Multi values.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes done that now, only have to wait 2 days before I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Values variable was used as a string, which MYSQL - connector doesn't iterate through. To solve this I change the Values Variable to a list:

```py
def insert(self,table_name, params):      
        fields = ''
        values = [] # changed to List instead of String
        placeholders = ''

        query = 'INSERT INTO {} '. format(table_name)
        for key in params:
            fields = fields + str(key) + ', '
            values.append(params[key])
            placeholders = placeholders + str('%s, ')

        fields = fields[:-2]
        placeholders = placeholders[:-2]
        query = query + '(' + fields + ')' + ' VALUES ' + '(' + placeholders + ')'
        print(query)
        print(values)
        try:
            Cursor = myDB.cursor()
            Cursor.execute(operation=query, params=values, multi=False)
            myDB.commit()
            print(Cursor.rowcount, ' Record inserted')
        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print(error)
        except:
            print ('Some errors')
        finally:    
            Cursor.close()
```